# C++ function always takes values of a previous call

Tags: c++

I see weird behavior in a program that I am writing using the NewTek NDI SDK for receiving video. It basically receives frames from a video source, and I can then handle each frame individually:

```
void handle_frame(NDIlib_video_frame_v2_t &video_frame)
{
  printf(
    "Frame received (%dx%d), timestamp: %ld, timecode: %ld, timestamp_ms: %f, timecode_ms: %f, metadata: %s",
    video_frame.xres,
    video_frame.yres,
    video_frame.timestamp,
    video_frame.timecode,
    (float)video_frame.timestamp / 10000.0f,
    (float)video_frame.timecode / 10000.0f,
    video_frame.p_metadata
  );
}

void receive_frames(NDIlib_recv_instance_t &pNDI_recv)
{
  while (true) {
    NDIlib_video_frame_v2_t video_frame;
    NDIlib_frame_type_e frame_type = NDIlib_recv_capture_v2(pNDI_recv, &video_frame, nullptr, nullptr, 5000);
    switch (frame_type) {
    case NDIlib_frame_type_video:
      handle_frame(video_frame);
      NDIlib_recv_free_video_v2(pNDI_recv, &video_frame);
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, this is the output I get for a few subsequent calls:

`Frame received (1920x1080), timestamp: 16170169126246802, timecode: 16170169126639307, timestamp_ms: 1617016913920.000000, timecode_ms: 1617016913920.000000, metadata: (null)`

`Frame received (1920x1080), timestamp: 16170169126593547, timecode: 16170169126972974, timestamp_ms: 1617016913920.000000, timecode_ms: 1617016913920.000000, metadata: (null)`

`Frame received (1920x1080), timestamp: 16170169126832240, timecode: 16170169127306641, timestamp_ms: 1617016913920.000000, timecode_ms: 1617016913920.000000, metadata: (null)`

Notice that the timestamp/timecode values change on every call, but once I divide them and log them, they are … always the same! They always take the value of the first time I made the division (`1617016913920.000000`).

What's even weirder is that they take the same value, despite using `timestamp` and `timecode` for both.

How can this be? How could the function use the value of a previous call?

Could it be that the `video_frame` instance underneath was changed somehow? But how could the other printed values then be correct in the context?

Even when I print the (divided) values directly inside the `case` branch, the result is the same.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I cannot explain it.

Comment: `float`s are too inaccurate for numbers this large so you will get a lot of rounded results.

Comment: @dave Ohh, gotcha, the value being "reused" was a red herring. Could you post that as an answer? Using `double` seems to do the trick.

Comment: `float` has a precision of `6` significant digits, on all the platforms I tested (granted, it might be different on yours: `std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10`). The value, that you are printing has more than `6` significant digits. Hence, it didn't change: it was truncated to nearest value, that can be represented with `float`). Related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: It is often a bad idea to hold time values as `double`s.  Keep the API's in-built return value -- presumably chosen for a reason.  Or translate it to a standard type for your language; for C++ that might be [`chrono::time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point).

Answer (score 1):

`float` values get increasingly inaccurate for large values (due to the representation in memory). In your case the next/previous representable values are spaced quite far apart:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
        std::cout << std::setprecision(20)
                << std::nextafter(1617016913920.f, 0.f) << "\n"
                << 1617016913920.f << "\n"
                << std::nextafter(1617016913920.f, 100000000000000.f) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1617016782848
1617016913920
1617017044992
```

Using `double` will increase the precision but it is probably still the wrong datatype to use in this situation. Use integer types or something like [chrono::duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) instead to avoid this issue.

Comment: Timestamp is `int64_t` and it signifies 100 ns intervals (weird non-SI unit choice, but whatever), so how do I precisely divide by 10000 then? You mean I could create a `time_point` from `timestamp`, then cast it using `duration_cast`?

Comment: What I would probably do is create a `std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::ratio<1, 10000000>>` and then use `std::chrono::duration_cast` for conversions

Comment: Note that `std::chrono::duration<>` is explicitly intended to support floating-point types. That won't avoid the issue you mentioned. But in this case, with the `/ 10000.0f` suggesting a 1E-4 resolution, I'd use a duration which counts exactly that: `std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::ratio<1, 10000>>`. With `int32_t`, you could count up to 596 hours. That might be enough.

Comment: @dave Thanks, I see the usefulness of creating a dedicated type for the "100 ns units". In this puzzle I kind of miss the way how to instantiate the duration from the nanoseconds timestamp I have. All I see is how to instantiate it from seconds. How would function `double timecode_to_ms(int64_t timestamp) { … }` look like if I wanted to improve on returning `(double)timestamp / 10000.0`?